# Using transform.forward on objects that are also being moved?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm continuing work on a script that lets me drag and drop objects, but now I need to figure out how to get them to move on the Z-axis. I'm trying to do this through button inputs. My current method has been to use transform forward, and my code doesn't really have any errors, but the problem lies in that Unity doesn't have a reference, and I'm not really sure what it's looking for.

This is my full code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DragNDrop : MonoBehaviour
{

    //Initialize Variables
    GameObject getTarget;
    bool isMouseDragging;
    Vector3 offsetValue;
    Vector3 positionOfScreen;
    Rigidbody m_rigidbody;
    float boxspeed;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        boxspeed = 5;
    }

    void Update()
    {

        //Mouse Button Press Down
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hitInfo;
            getTarget = ReturnClickedObject(out hitInfo);
            if (getTarget.tag == "Box")
            {
                m_rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
                isMouseDragging = true;
                //Converting world position to screen position.
                positionOfScreen = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(getTarget.transform.position);
                offsetValue = getTarget.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, positionOfScreen.z));
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
                {
                    //Move the Rigidbody forwards constantly at speed you define (the blue arrow axis in Scene view)
                    m_rigidbody.velocity = transform.forward * boxspeed;
                }
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
                {
                    //Move the Rigidbody forwards constantly at speed you define (the blue arrow axis in Scene view)
                    boxspeed = -5;
                    m_rigidbody.velocity = transform.forward * boxspeed;
                }
            }
        }

        //Mouse Button Up
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
        {
            isMouseDragging = false;
        }

        //Is mouse Moving
        if (isMouseDragging)
        {
            //tracking mouse position.
            Vector3 currentScreenSpace = new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, positionOfScreen.z);

            //converting screen position to world position with offset changes.
            Vector3 currentPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(currentScreenSpace) + offsetValue;

            //It will update target gameobject's current postion.
            getTarget.transform.position = currentPosition;
        }


    }

    //Method to Return Clicked Object
    GameObject ReturnClickedObject(out RaycastHit hit)
    {
        GameObject target = null;
        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);
        if (Physics.Raycast(ray.origin, ray.direction * 10, out hit))
        {
            target = hit.collider.gameObject;
        }
        return target;
    }

}
```

The part thats specifically causing the error is the Update function, here:

```
void Update()
    {

        //Mouse Button Press Down
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            RaycastHit hitInfo;
            getTarget = ReturnClickedObject(out hitInfo);
            if (getTarget.tag == "Box")
            {
                m_rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
                isMouseDragging = true;
                //Converting world position to screen position.
                positionOfScreen = Camera.main.WorldToScreenPoint(getTarget.transform.position);
                offsetValue = getTarget.transform.position - Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector3(Input.mousePosition.x, Input.mousePosition.y, positionOfScreen.z));
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.UpArrow))
                {
                    //Move the Rigidbody forwards constantly at speed you define (the blue arrow axis in Scene view)
                    m_rigidbody.velocity = transform.forward * boxspeed;
                }
                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.DownArrow))
                {
                    //Move the Rigidbody forwards constantly at speed you define (the blue arrow axis in Scene view)
                    boxspeed = -5;
                    m_rigidbody.velocity = transform.forward * boxspeed;
                }
            }
        }
```

The error I get states this:

> NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
>   DragNDrop.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/DragNDrop.cs:30)

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thank you very much!

Comment: You should check if getTarget isn't null before trying to access its properties.

Comment: You expect ReturnClickedObject to return a valid reference but it may not hit anything and return null. The if statement about the Raycast may not be true, then it returns a null target. You can add if (getTarget != null && getTarget.tag == "Box") or as such if (getTarget?.tag == "Box"), notice the question mark.

Comment: would this be surrounding my key inputs? @Everts

Comment: No, you'd just add a new check in the if statement before checking for the tag.

Answer (score 1):

As already said your `ReturnClickedObject` returns `null` if there was no hit ...

You should not use `== null` or Nullables (`?.`) on references of type `UnityEngine.Object` (basically all Unity reference types).

Also note that you should not directly `==` tags but rather use [`CompareTag`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.CompareTag.html). It throws an exception if the given tag was misspelled or doesn't exist at all. A "bug" which would be hidden by `==` costing you development time and nerves. Additionally it is very slightly faster.

---

Simply change your check to

```
getTarget = ReturnClickedObject(out hitInfo);
if (getTarget && getTarget.CompareTag("Box"))
```

---

A general note: Store and re-use references! `GetComponent` e.g. is a quite expensive call. The same for `Camera.main` which internally uses something like `FindObjectWithTag`. Rather use e.g.

```
// If possible already reference these via the Inspector to
// skip GetComponent entirely!
[SerializeField] private Rigidbody _rigidbody;
[Serializefield] private Camera mainCamera;

private void Start()
{
    if(!_rigidbody) _rigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    if(!mainCamera) mainCamera = Camera.main;
}
```

and later

```
_rigidbody.velocity = ...
```

and

```
mainCamera.WorldToScreenPoint(...)
```

Comment: I think the usage of null and ? on GameObject is not recommended when you deal with references on object that may get destroyed. In this case, there is a null reference declared and the raycast check will populate or not, it is then used in the same frame. So the null check should go fine.

Comment: @Everts I only know that `?.` in Visualtudio(+ReSharper) in general gives a compiler warning `Using '?.' on a type deriving from 'UnityEngine.Object' bypasses the lifetime check on the underlying Unity engine object.` The `== null` is marked as very performance intense with a recommendation of rather using the `bool` operator